# Issue with UPDATE multiple rows in one query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert-update

I have an error when I proceed to UPDATE multiple rows in my script, this issue it doesn't always happen, but when happen update successfully but in another table without any reference or cardinality change the existences in two or more items.

Here my code to UPDATE:

```
$ref_venta = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'refIdFactura', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `PRODUCTOS` SET `refIdFactura` = :refIdFactura WHERE `id_p` = :id_p");
foreach($_POST['facturar'] as $i => $id_p) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':refIdFactura', $ref_venta);  // is a number of receipt
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_p', $_POST['facturar'][$i]); //is the id of each item in the list
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Like I said here is working properly, but when the issue happen this UPDATE this other table too and is not listed in the script:

```
TABLE NAME:  `LPRODUCTOS` ---- ROWS: idP, existences
```

There are two tables with primary keys different and if you see in the UPDATE I never capture the row with existences and The id(`id_p`) of the TABLE `PRODUCTOS` is not the same of the id (`idP`) of TABLE `LPRODUCTOS`

So I don't know why this happen...

Comment: check if there is a trigger for the table

Comment: @nbk there is no trigger in the table

Comment: then problem can only occur when in $_POST['facturar'] are two ids , so echo that and see what is the content

Comment: @nbk, yes in the `facturar` there are more than two id in each time (1234,1235,1236,1240, etc) is an array those numbers are the id (id_p) for the table `PRODUCTOS` an in each id the row `refIdFactura` will be change

Comment: so it runs 4 time and add to all 4 ids the ref_venda and add the same tiome you get in another table LPRODUCTOS equal amounts of new rows. look there is a trigger at work. AN AFTER UPDATE on PRODUCTOS

Comment: mmm that depends, some times there are more than 11 items per time, but if you see in the update script I never call the TABLE `LPRODUCTOS`,  there is not use it for all I only call the table `PRODUCTOS` for change the number of the receipt in each item. the receipt is a correlative number. I dont know why change the existences in the other table, how can I block that?

Comment: as it doesn't come from the script at least not in the part  you shown, so you have to look in phpmyadmin or mysql workbench to find the cause

Comment: How can I create a trigger blocked that?, can you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is are `foreign key constraints` between the two tables. This may cause the update on the 2nd table if you're updating the 1st.

Check with:

```sql
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMN_NAME,
  CONSTRAINT_NAME,   -- <<-- the one you want! 
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IN ('LPRODUCTOS', 'PRODUCTOS');
```

This should show your indexes incld. constraints.

Learn more [foreign key constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Show me this: `Array ( [Table] => LPRODUCTOS [Non_unique] => 0 [Key_name] => PRIMARY [Seq_in_index] => 1 [Column_name] => idP [Collation] => A [Cardinality] => 1631 [Sub_part] => [Packed] => [Null] => [Index_type] => BTREE [Comment] => [Index_comment] => )
-----------
Array ( [Table] => PRODUCTOS [Non_unique] => 0 [Key_name] => PRIMARY [Seq_in_index] => 1 [Column_name] => id_p [Collation] => A [Cardinality] => 22335 [Sub_part] => [Packed] => [Null] => [Index_type] => BTREE [Comment] => [Index_comment] => )`

Comment: It doesn't seem like `foreign key` taking action then. Maybe `triggers`... Does `SHOW TRIGGERS` show anything?

Comment: I'm finished with suggestions, sorry :(